# Footer.php displaying different on different pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to update our mobile site over the last week but I'm hitting an issue with the footer. It loads up just fine on the home page but crashes when on a normal page. Both are using the same footer.php file.

The staging site that I'm working on is:
http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 */
?>    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div><!-- .site_content .inner-wrapper -->
         </div><!-- .site_content -->
            <?php if(!is_front_page()):?>
    <?php if(!is_page(52)):?>
                <div class="page-cta">
         <h4 style="font-family: Georgia;font-size: 40px !important; font-weight: bold; color: #075aa0;">Free, No Obligation</h4>
         <h5 style="font-size: 40px !important; font-weight: 500; line-height: .6 !important; margin-top: 0px; color: #075aa0;;">Disability Evalution</h5>
         <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #39393b; width:90%;">
         <p style="font-size: 30px !important;">Let us help you determine if you<br>qualify for disability income<p>
         <div style="height:20px;"></div>
         <a title="Free social Security Evaluation" href="http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/contact-us/free-evaluation/">Free Evaluation</a>
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>
            <img src="http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Premier_Bottom_Logos.png" />
            <?php else:?>
            <div class="home-map">
             <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <?php
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_parent' => 56,
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
                $children = get_children( $args );
                ?>
                <?php if($children):?>
                    <div class="state-list">
                        <p style="align:left; Color:#a32a2f; margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Click the map below<br>for more state information</b></p>
            <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 570px; border-top: 2px solid #a32a2f;" />
            <p align="left">All 50 states and territories</p>
                        <a href="https://m.premierdisability.com/the-premier-difference/nationwide-disability-benefits/"><img src="http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Premier_Map.svg" alt="Premier Disability offers nationwide help"/>
                            &nbsp;
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif;?>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <div class="site-footer">
                <div class="footer-disclamier">
                  <div class="inner-back">
                        <div class="inner-wrapper" style="background-color: #e3e3e3; width: 640px; margin: -20px 0px 0px -40px; padding: 20px 0px;">
                          <p class="sharelink">Keep in touch</p>
                            <div style="padding-bottom:80px;" class="social relative">
                                <div style="position: absolute; left: 20%;">
                              <a class="block left" href="https://www.facebook.com/PremierDisability" target="_blank"><img src="http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Facebook-Icon.jpg" style="width:60px;"></a>
                  <a class="block left" href="https://plus.google.com/110325482012270783070" target="_blank"><img src="https://m.premierdisability.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/GooglePlus-Icon.png" style="width:60px;"></a>
                                  <a class="block left" href="https://twitter.com/PremierDisSvcs" target="_blank"><img src="https://m.premierdisability.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Twitter-Icon.png" style="width:60px;"></a>
                                  <a class="block left" href="https://www.instagram.com/premierdisabilityservices/" target="_blank"><img src="https://m.premierdisability.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Instagram-Icon.png" style="width:60px;"></a>
                                </div>
                <div style="padding: 0px 109px; margin-top: 90px;">
                  <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/premier-ssd/id1143571193?mt=8"><div class="applink Apple"></div></a>
                  <a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodbarber.premierdis&utm_source=global_co&utm_medium=prtnr&utm_content=Mar2515&utm_campaign=PartBadge&pcampaignid=MKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1'><div class="applink Google"></div></a>
                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="small-disclaimer"><p style="font-size:12px !important;margin-top: 20px;line-height:1.2;"><b>Disclaimer:</b> We are a privately owned, nationwide advocacy service. Any information you receive on this site is not intended to be, nor should it be construed as, legal advice. Using this website or contacting us does not create any type of legal or fiduciary relationship. Premier Disability Services, LLC is neither affiliated with nor endorsed by the Social Security Administration or any other government agency or entity.</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="copyright">
                 <div class="inner-back">
                        <div class="inner-wrapper">
                            <?php Theme::getCopyright()?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </div><!-- .site-footer -->
  </div><!-- #main .wrapper -->
 </div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the footer php into its own php file. Then simply [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file at the end of the page. I use this and it works.

To do this, take the code from the `wp_footer()` function and paste it in a new file.

Then `include 'new-wp-footer.php';` on pages where it doesn't show up.

Update:

Try to turn on output buffering before you include. Then grab the the contents.

For example,

```
    ob_start();
    include('footer.php');
    $footer_content = ob_get_clean();
    echo $footer_content;
```

Comment: Thanks Harman for your quick response. But that's actually how it's set up right now.

Comment: http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Homepage-footer-code.png

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that. Okay, try to turn on output buffering before the include line, and then use `ob_get_clean`. Check updated answer

Comment: If I replaced the <? get_footer(); ?> this is what gets displayed. http://premierdism.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Homepage-footer-code2.png

Answer (score 0):

You can change `margin-top: 90px` to `padding-top: 90px`, in this spot:

```
<div style="padding: 0px 109px; margin-top: 90px;">
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/premier-ssd/id1143571193?mt=8">
    <div class="applink Apple"></div>
</a>
<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodbarber.premierdis&utm_source=global_co&utm_medium=prtnr&utm_content=Mar2515&utm_campaign=PartBadge&pcampaignid=MKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1'>
    <div class="applink Google"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did make them place correctly across all pages. But it's still not applying the CSS code to the line of text "Keep in touch." I already applied the style inline and it works fine now. But it still confuses/worries me why it's stripping the information when applied to other pages. Any other ideas how to fix it other than inline coding the footer?

Comment: Hi IamDade89, if you mean that the `font-size` is not the same as on the homepage, that is because you have a `.footer-disclamier .inner-wrapper > p` which only targets `p` elements which are direct children of the `.inner-wrapper` element. This is not the case on your homepage where the `p` has an enclosing `a` tag. More about the `>` selector can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi IamDade89, did that answer your question?